# Adding circles to multiline graph with d3.js

Tags: graph, d3.js

so I'm trying to add circles to each datapoint on this graph:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

Any idea on how to do this? Thanks.

Here is what I tried for now:

```
var circles = focus.selectAll("g") 
    .data(values) 
    .enter() 
    .append("g"); 

circles.append("circle") 
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.date; }) 
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.temperature; }) 
    .attr("r", function (d) { return 4; });
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. What have you tried?

Comment: @ChristopherChiche I tried to use this:

var circles = focus.selectAll("g")
                          .data(values)
                          .enter()
                          .append("g");

               circles.append("circle")
                       .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.date; })
                       .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.temperature; })
                       .attr("r", function (d) { return 4; });

but that's not working. And a lot of other variations on the code.

Comment: Could you add the code to your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can append circles for each point of a given city:

```
city.append("g").selectAll("circle")
  .data(function(d){return d.values})
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 2)
  .attr("cx", function(dd){return x(dd.date)})
  .attr("cy", function(dd){return y(dd.temperature)})
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
```

Result: http://bl.ocks.org/ChrisJamesC/5896521/943f325deacb4a533e086d56478c1e76b6c6b4bd

By the way, this method does not work with the `basis` interpolation as points seem to be far from the line. You might have to do more work if you need the interpolation but I doubt that as highlighting each points of the curve certainly means that you want to have their exact position.

**EDIT:** 
In order to have a the circle to be the same color as the line, you need to access the data of the parentNode:

```
.attr("stroke", function(d){return color(this.parentNode.__data__.name)})
```

New result: http://bl.ocks.org/ChrisJamesC/5896521/83d7c5c04f7d031d3c71b4d6fd5b5193366d9fed

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Do you know how I would change the colors of the circle to that of their respective lines?

Comment: @ChristopherChiche Hi, if I need to append circle with basis interpolation what should i do? I am new to d3js.

Comment: @TonyRoczz you should write another question. But the interpolation should be done on the axis/domain level