# D3js and specific datapoints shown as small circles

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using a line chart similar to http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955 and use it without too many problems. My chart is showing realtime score data of an audience (with each participant having his own line).

Now, I also permit the participant to add a comment during the event they score. This event should show up as a small circles on the line. The admin overlooking the event will be able to get a tooltip with the comment.

I tried to handle the line and the circles fully independant but run into troubles with color (line and circles do not have matching color) and the fact that I use the basis interpolation

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
.interpolate("basis")
.x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.status); });
```

The circles which are on "true" x and y values hence get plotted outside of the curve (which is interpolated).

So, I need to use a single data set looking like this

```
data = [
    {time: 1, score: 40},
    {time: 2, score: 30},
    ...
    {time: 345, score : 70, comment: great connection to the market data},
    {time: 346, score : 70}
    ....
]
```

Can anyone help please as I am lost with this one since 3 days now

cheers
Peter

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394006/adding-circles-to-multiline-graph-with-d3-js)?

Comment: yes, I have seen, but... I don't want to add circles to every point of the line. I want to have circles only if I have a comment added by a participant at that timeslot. So, I have one additional data per line whci is the comment. If it is not defined, there is no comment and hence no circle, if it is defined, there is a circle. Sorry, seems maybe a bad explanation, but I am stuck. Help is highly appreciated

Comment: The principle will be the same -- simply filter your data so that you're only using the points that have a comment for the selection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time spent on this. The problem is I need more details of actual coding as D3.js is real steep learning curve.

Comment: Ok, so something like `var commentData = data.filter(function(d) { return d.comment !== null; })` and then use `commentData` in a selection `svg.selectAll("circle").data(commentData).enter().append("circle")...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use d3.color type. Here is the working fiddle of line chart with basic interpolation, data points and tool-tip. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Rk5N/60/)

For datapoints :-

```
var circles = activityLine.selectAll("circle")
    .data(function(d) {        
        return(d.values);
    })
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("stroke", function(d, i) {
        if(d.values[i])
            return color(d.values[i].activity);
    })
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(dateFormat.parse(d.key));


    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d.values.length);
    })    
    .attr("stroke-width", 4.8)
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.0001)
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0.0001);
```

For tooltip :-

```
 circles.append("title")
    .text(function(d,i){        
      return d.values[i]!=undefined?d.values[i].activity:"text";
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not solve my issue. The circles should be only added when a a certain datapoint (in my case a timeline) a participant has given an comment. if you can help, it really blocks me here. And, BTW, the problem with the datapoints not being on the interpolated "basis" line is solved as you can select "cardinal" as interpolation which ensures that the line goes thru a datapoint